# Using Windows raw_input in NPAPI windowed plugin in Chrome

Tags: c, windows, google-chrome, npapi

I have an application which is working fine standalone. It handles all its keyboard/mouse input using raw input. When switching to NPAPI client windowed plugin, I receive inputs via `WM_KEYDOWN` for keyboard, whereas they're supposed to be disabled by my setup, and worse I do NOT receive any raw input `WM_INPUT` event for keyboard. Everything else is working, including D3D9 rendering in the window.

Here's how I setup the window roughly (it's quite lengthy):

```
...
SetWindowLongPtr(Application_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&Application_WndProc);
...

DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE notificationFilter;
GUID hid = { 0 };
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[4] = { 0 };

rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01; // HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC (in WDK)
rid[1].usUsage = 0x06; // HID_USAGE_GENERIC_KEYBOARD (in WDK)
rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;//RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY;
rid[1].hwndTarget = Application_hWnd; // capture only for this window

RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, sizeof(rid) / sizeof(rid[0]), sizeof(rid[0]));
... other raw device detection and related HID stuff
```

Receiving:

```
case WM_INPUT:
{
     if (GET_RAWINPUT_CODE_WPARAM(wParam) == RIM_INPUT)
     {
            RAWINPUT raw = { 0 };
            UINT dwSize = sizeof(raw);

            if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, &raw, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) > 0)
            {
                switch (raw.header.dwType)
                {
                case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
                    // never reaches here
```

Error checking is omitted here for clarity, but no error is reported anywhere. Yet it seems to have no effect for keyboard, but I do receive WM_INPUT for mouse.

Anyone has a successfully working raw input keyboard in NPAPI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try creating your own child HWND inside the one the browser gives you where you'll have more control of what is going on.

Comment: Indeed that works. Arr but now I have to handle the style, position and size of the window myself. I still wonder why we can't manipulate the provided window as we want.
Anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: if you make the window a child of the other window and do it correctly you should get position and size automatically. I'm speaking based on things others have said, though; I haven't ever done it myself, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ah interesting, I'll try that. I've simply set the parent of the window after its creation when testing the solution, but yeah I could try specifying the parent at window creation time.

Comment: Hmm didn't work for me, the position was not correct and always on top in the browser, maybe I do things not correctly. I went back to SetParent with SetWindowPlacement with placement taken from the NPAPI window, and it's working fine.
Thanks !